# Ubuntu 18.10 Crashes out within seconds of logging in from time to time

Tags: boot, 18.10

so I'm relatively new to Linux - working on using it as my daily (except for games).

Every 3rd or so fresh restart, when I log in, within minutes of logging in, the computer freezes. The mouse still can move around the screen, but everything else is locked.

Just so you know it's a PC computer -  with 8700k cpu and gtx1080ti, 16gb ram

The error log I see when this happens is very odd, I get a repeating string that goes for a long time, the last entries look like this:

Jan 11 07:29:45 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Reloading.

Jan 11 07:29:45 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for vlc, revision 770...

Jan 11 07:29:45 ubuntu-linux systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for vlc, revision 770.

Jan 11 07:29:46 ubuntu-linux gnome-shell[4852]: setup_framebuffers: assertion 'width > 0' failed

\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00...

that repeats for a while...  evidently I'm assuming until I reset the compute.

Any ideas on how I could address this?

Comment: sounds like those errors are coming from vlc ... I suggest you launch a new terminal or at a minimum a new terminal tab for anything other than your vlc so its errors will not get displayed when not using vlc

Comment: Well I hadn't actually opened anything other than Chrome at the time this happened - I booted up the computer, logged in, and opened chrome. But other times I haven't even made it to chrome before it crashed. - You're right however that something related to vlc appears to have started even though vlc isn't in the startup apps either...

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall vlc and see if that fixes it ... typically vlc is stable however I find that applications installed using the new snap approach tend to be unstable ... lets see if vlc was installed using snap ... issue this in a terminal ( ctrl+alt+t )

```
sudo snap list
sudo snap list | grep vlc
```

if you see vlc appear in output of above then lets uninstall it using

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

it may not be called simply vlc so use what its called from above snap list output

If problem goes away after uninstalling vlc as per above, and you need vlc (who doesn't ?) then install vlc the normal way using

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```